# CSS Grid. Центрирование трёх элементов

Tags: css, css3, css-grid

У меня есть 3 элемента, решил их сделать адаптивным с помощью CSS Grid.

```css
.elements-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="elements-wrapper">
  <div class="element-1"></div>
  <div class="element-2"></div>
  <div class="element-2"></div>
</div>
```

Все работает, но на маленьких экранах где то после 1200 третий элемент опускается вниз и располагается по левому или по правому краю.

```
 | element1 | | element2 |      или  | element1 | | element2 |
 | element3 |                                     | element3 |
```

А я хочу чтоб он был в центре. Ну примерно вот такой вид нужен.

```
| element1 |  | element 2 |
       |element 3 |
```

Comment: А что мешает использовать media query?

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как с помощью CSS Grid, там все же строго по сетке все. А вот с помощью Flexbox это просто.

1. Задаем контейнеру свойство `flex-wrap` со значением `wrap`, чтобы элементы переходили на следующую строку, а не сжимались.
2. Контейнеру задаем свойство `justify-content: center`, оно как раз и отцентрует нижний элемент.

```css
.elements-wrapper-flex {
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.element-flex {
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 0 0 300px;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="elements-wrapper-flex">
  <div class="element-flex">1</div>
  <div class="element-flex">2</div>
  <div class="element-flex">3</div>
</div>
```